# Find $x$ such that the vectors $\langle 3,2,x \rangle$ and $\langle 2x,4,x \rangle$ are parallel

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Find $x$ such that the vectors $\langle 3,2,x \rangle$ and $\langle 2x,4,x \rangle$ are parallel. I tried to do $a=kb$ but there was no constant $k$ value so I don't know if that was the right thing to do.

Answer (score 4):

In order for two vectors to be parallel, one has to be a multiple of the other, say
$$
r\langle 3,2,x \rangle = \langle 2x,4,x \rangle
\qquad
\text{for some scalar } r.
$$
This is a system of three equations, one for each component of the vector:
$$
\begin{cases} 
3r = 2x & \\
2r = 4 & \\ 
xr = x &
\end{cases} 
$$
The second equation shows that $r=2$, which makes the third equation into $2x = x$, so $x=0$. But then the first equation reads $6 = 0$, which is impossible.

Therefore, no such scale factor $r$ exists, and these two vectors are always linearly independent.